# Best Practice to create static roles with permissions

Tags: permissions, abp

I am using abp 4.1.2 and I am struggling to find best practices where to create static roles programmatically (including permissions).

Context: For my application, I have several permissions created. I want to programmatically create a set of Roles that will have specific permissions so I can assign them to users later.

I can create the roles using IDataSeedContributor, but at this time we still don't have the permissions created, hence granting permissions fails with "No permission XXX".

What is the advice to create static roles and grant them permissions as part of the application code?

Comment: Did you examine the [Permission Management](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Authorization#permission-management) section in Authorization documentation? Because after you created users and related roles, you can inject IPermissionManager and use the `SetForUserAsync` or `SetForRoleAsync` method to assign permissions to users or roles as documented.

Comment: That sections explains how to add permissions to roles. Not how you can create static roles